# Mysql - how to create an id column for a specific column

Tags: mysql, mysql-8.0, wamp

i want to create a table that have 3 column :

1. visit_times : have a unique id for every specific visitor
2. visitor_ID
3. Date

i tryed to create the table as showing this code

> CREATE TABLE `test`.`table` ( `visit_times` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT , `visitor_ID` INT NOT NULL , `Date` VARCHAR NOT NULL , UNIQUE `Unique column` (`visit_times`, `visitor_ID`)) ENGINE = MyISAM;

but when i store this data into the table

```
INSERT INTO `tab`(`visitor_ID`, `date`) VALUES ("1", "15/05/2021");
INSERT INTO `tab`(`visitor_ID`, `date`) VALUES ("1", "20/07/2021");
INSERT INTO `tab`(`visitor_ID`, `date`) VALUES ("2", "02/09/2021");
INSERT INTO `tab`(`visitor_ID`, `date`) VALUES ("3", "24/08/2021");
```

the result it will be like this

| visit_times | visitor_ID | date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 15/05/2021 |
| 2 | 1 | 20/07/2021 |
| 3 | 2 | 02/09/2021 |
| 4 | 3 | 24/08/2021 |

and what i actually want as result

| visit_times | visitor_ID | date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 15/05/2021 |
| 2 | 1 | 20/07/2021 |
| 1 | 2 | 02/09/2021 |
| 1 | 3 | 24/08/2021 |

Server version: 8.0.21 - MySQL Community Server - GPL

I use Wampserver version 3.2.3 - 64bit

Apache Version : 2.4.46

Comment: Get your `visit_times` using a window function. Don't store dates in a `varchar` column. Use a `date` column. Welcome to SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming `visit_times` means the nth time a user has visited.

You can't do it with `AUTO_INCREMENT`. You have 2 options:

**1-** Inserting `visit_times` value while inserting rows:

```
SET @visitTimes = IFNULL((SELECT visit_times FROM tab WHERE visitor_ID = 3 
ORDER BY visit_times DESC LIMIT 1), 0)+1;
INSERT INTO tab(visit_times, visitor_ID, date) 
VALUES (@visitTimes , "3", "24/08/2021");
```

**2-** Using a [Trigger](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/trigger-syntax.html):

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS setVisitTimesOnTab$$

CREATE TRIGGER setVisitTimesOnTab
    BEFORE INSERT
    ON tab
    FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    SET NEW.visit_times = IFNULL((SELECT visit_times FROM tab
                                  WHERE visitor_ID = NEW.visitor_ID
                                  ORDER BY visit_times DESC
                                  LIMIT 1), 0) + 1;
END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

Using a trigger is a simpler approach.

Comment: thank you so much :) <33